# TypeORM- findOne returns unexpected value

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I have a User Entity with an Email Column. When I use TypeORM's findOne function to search for a Email which doesn't exist in the database, findOne returns the first entry to the User Entity for some reason. This function seems not to work like in the documentation.

**findOne:**

```
// returns the first User of database
const user = await this.userRepository.findOne({ email: 'this@mailisnotindatabase.de' });
```

**User.Entity.ts:**

```
import {
  Entity,
  Column,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ name: 'id' })
  private _id: number;

  @Column({ name: 'password', length: 256, nullable: true })
  private _password?: string;

  @Column({ name: 'email', length: 300, nullable: true, unique: true })
  private _email?: string;

  @Column({ name: 'roles', length: 300, nullable: true })
  private _roles?: string = null;

  public get id(): number {
    return this._id;
  }

  public set id(id: number) {
    this._id = id;
  }

  public get email(): string {
    return this._email;
  }

  public set email(email: string) {
    this._email = email;
  }

  public get password(): string {
    return this._password;
  }

  public set password(password: string) {
    this._password = password;
  }

  public get roles(): string {
    return this._roles;
  }

  public set roles(roles: string) {
    this._roles = roles;
  }
}
```

This is from the official documentation:

> const user = new User(); user.firstName = "Timber"; user.lastName =
>   "Saw"; user.age = 25; await repository.save(user);
>
> const allUsers = await repository.find(); const firstUser = await
>   repository.findOne(1); // find by id const timber = await
>   repository.findOne({ firstName: "Timber", lastName: "Saw" });
>
> await repository.remove(timber);

Answer (score 27):

Works for me:

```
const user = await this.userRepository.findOne(
    { where:
        { email: 'this@mailisnotindatabase.de' }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 5):

This is an active issue, the discussion is available in the following link:
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2500

My workaround on this issue is the following:

```
const usersRepository = conn.getRepository(UserEntity);

const results = await usersRepository.find({
    relations: ['profile'],
        where: {
            email: username
        },
        take: 1 
    });
// ...
```

`find` will return an array, you should check the length of the array to confirm the rows match the `WHERE` clause executed.

What happens with the current `findOne` implementation is that when a row is not found with the required values, the first row of the table in question is being returned.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

for applying condition, you should use where key in object of findOne as an argument like example below:

```
const user = await this.userRepository.findOne({ where:{ email:'this@mailisnotindatabase.de' }});
```

here is documentation of all Find methods' options:
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/find-options.md

Answer (score 4):

Since `User.email` property is a function and not a string, your `findOne` query essentially tries to find an entity whose `email` function equals `'this@mailisnotindatabase.de'` which naturally doesn't work. The actual email column in your model is `_email`, which as a private property cannot be referenced to in a TypeORM query.

There's a couple of options here:

1. Get rid of your getters and setters. TypeORM [does not support](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3548) this form of encapsulation. Instead you can wrap your TypeORM Entity class with another domain model class for encapsulation, or if you're using getters/setters to transform values before db insert/select you could use [TypeORM's value transformers](https://typeorm.io/#/entities/column-options) instead.
2. Use `QueryBuilder` for your queries instead of the `find`/`findOne`/etc methods. `QueryBuilder` [can refer to any arbitrary column](https://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder/how-to-create-and-use-a-querybuilder).

Answer (score 0):

Type ORM Works for me:

```
let userData;
let userRepository = getRepository(User);
userData = await userRepository
                .findOne({
                    where: {"email":'navalkishor2005@gmail.com'}
                });
```

Comment: Consider reading the following issue:
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2500

Be careful about this behavior this could lead to data leak.